# Grouping Customer Sessions by Customer and Time until Next Transaction

Tags: r, tidyverse

I need to bucket customer shopping sessions by time until next transaction. An example data frame is:

```
library(tidyverse)

cust_transactions_before <- 
  tibble(
    customer_name = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
    time_until_next =c(41, 19, 5, 27, 49, 3, 10, 20, 13, NA_integer_, 25, 17, 8, 33, 25, 31, 19, 5, 27, NA_integer_))
```

I would like to group by `customer_name` and have the first transaction per customer start at 1 for the value `cust_session`. For the next observation I'd like to do an if/then where if `time_until_next` is <= 30 then keep the same session number for `cust_session` as the previous observation. If `time_until_next` is > 30 then take the previous `cust_session` and add 1 to it.

Lastly, if `time_until_next` is NA then have it equal the previous `cust_session`.

A successful data frame after processing would look like this:

```
cust_transactions_after <- 
  tibble(
    customer_name = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
    time_until_next =c(41, 19, 5, 27, 49, 3, 10, 20, 13, NA_integer_, 25, 17, 8, 33, 25, 31, 19, 5, 27, NA_integer_), 
    cust_session = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
cust_transactions_before %>% 
  group_by(customer_name) %>% 
  mutate(cust_session = cumsum(lag(time_until_next, default = 31) > 30))

   customer_name time_until_next cust_session
   <chr>                   <dbl>        <int>
 1 a                          41            1
 2 a                          19            2
 3 a                           5            2
 4 a                          27            2
 5 a                          49            2
 6 a                           3            3
 7 a                          10            3
 8 a                          20            3
 9 a                          13            3
10 a                          NA            3
11 b                          25            1
12 b                          17            1
13 b                           8            1
14 b                          33            1
15 b                          25            2
16 b                          31            2
17 b                          19            3
18 b                           5            3
19 b                          27            3
20 b                          NA            3
```